# Need help removing list box interior border

Tags: ms-access

I need quick help with something. I need help making the right border line on a the interior of a listbox disappear on an access form. Does any one know how? This is my current properties but the border right after the check box is still there.[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, I haven't been able to find a way to remove the borders inside of the listbox.  Would concatenating the fields in the box serve the same purpose you are looking for?

Comment: re: "the border right after the check box" - This is a List Box that is bound to a multi-value Lookup field, is it?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the border right after the check box and yes it is bound to a multi-value lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've ever seen, the ListBox control in Access has a bunch of GridLine properties that do absolutely nothing. If you are brave/willing to do a little research, the ActiveX Listview control has a lot more options (that actually work), but are a lot more complex.